# Extension Methods with variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, extension-methods

I have created this helper class RichTextBoxHelper that has an extension method, and I would like to write another WriteLine method or rewrite this one (which solution is best) in order to be able to use it in the function presented under it. Thank you.

```
public static class RichTextBoxHelper
{
    public static void WriteLine(this RichTextBox txtLog, object line)
    {
        txtLog.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

private void selectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vehicles = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>
    {
        Tuple.Create("123","VW",1999),
        Tuple.Create("234","Ford",2009),
        Tuple.Create("567","Audi",2005),
        Tuple.Create("678","Ford",2003),
        Tuple.Create("789","Mazda",2003),
        Tuple.Create("999","Ford",1965)
    };

    var fordCars = vehicles.Where(v => v.Item2 == "Ford")
                         .Select(v => new Car
                         {
                             VIN = v.Item1,
                             Make = v.Item2,
                             Year = v.Item3
                         });

    foreach (var item in fordCars)
        txtLog.WriteLine("Car VIN:{0} Make:{1} Year:{2}", item.VIN, item.Make, item.Year);                                    
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `No overload for method 'WriteLine' takes 4 arguments`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, that's completely possible. It's called method overloading and it works just as well on extension method classes as normal classes.

The signature you require for your new method is:

```
public static void WriteLine(
    this RichTextBox txtLog, 
    string format, 
    params object[] args)
{
    // ...
}
```

Just put it in the same class as your other one and you'll be able to use both as appropriate.

Alternatively you can call your existing method in the following way:

```
txtLog.WriteLine(
    String.Format(
        "Car VIN:{0} Make:{1} Year:{2}", 
        item.VIN, 
        item.Make, 
        item.Year));
```

Comment: Ok, I did It for a single object using format. `txtLog.AppendText(String.Format(format,line + Environment.NewLine));` Could you please explain me how should I make it work for an array of objects?

Comment: @TanatosDaniel I suggest you read up on [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did not notice the `param` keyword at first. That is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think dav_i answer is correct but I prefer you to write your extension method for IsIn method something like below, because you can use it everywhere for every different kind of variables:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsIn<T>(this T keyObject, params object[] collection)
    {
        return collection.Contains(keyObject);
    }
}
```

usage of method is like here:

```
if (intValue.IsIn( 2, 3, 7 ))
        {
            do something...
        }
if (stringVlaue.IsIn("a","b","c"))
  {
           do something...
  }
```